Nativewind is not working when functions are defined in tailwind.config.ts
I am using React Native, TypeScript, Expo and Nativewind.
I defined some functions and used it to customize tailwind classes.
And the style does not apply.
Tailwind.config.ts:
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
// const { range, pxToRem } = require('./utils/configHelper');

function range(start, end) {
  return Array.from({ length: end - start + 1 }, (_, i) => start + i);
};
  
function pxToRem(px) {
  return `${px / 16}rem`;
};

const spacing = range(1, 100).reduce((acc, px) => {
  acc[px] = pxToRem(px);
  return acc;
}, {});

// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    spacing: spacing,
    borderRadius: {
      sm: `${pxToRem(10)}`,
      md: `${pxToRem(20)}`,
      lg: `${pxToRem(30)}`,
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "#5A8CFF",
        },
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: "#FFD65B",
        },
        black: "#151820",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        lt: ['SpoqaHanSansNeo-Light', 'sans-serif'],
        rg: ['SpoqaHanSansNeo-Regular', 'sans-serif'],
        md: ['SpoqaHanSansNeo-Medium', 'sans-serif'],
        bd: ['SpoqaHanSansNeo-Bold', 'sans-serif'],
      },
      letterSpacing: {  // tracking
        lt: '-0.3px',
        rg: '-0.3px',
        md: '-0.2px',
        bd: '-0.1px',
      },
      fontSize: { // text
        sm: '16px',
        md: '20px',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};

I have tried chaning the config file into ts extention.
I also tried to separate the functions and config file and import them in the config file but it didn't work as well.
Thank you so much for you help in advance.
